# Hi i am developing an app in android using socket io

Tags: javascript, android, socket.io

if one client is browser and another is android ,if i refresh on browser side from  room, app gets closed in android,Can any one say if one client in a room gets disconnected from socket will other also gets disconnected automatically .How can i stop closing the app on mobile when other client gets disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Rooms can be sort of confusing if you know nothing about them.

A client automatically creates a room joining:

client with socket.id has room with id: socket.id;

A connected client will always be in that room.

A client can also `join` and `leave` other rooms, including another clients room. But you NEVER EVER want to do that. You as the server control which rooms the users join and leave.

If your app leaves a room after someone else leaves, it sounds like your app was actually connected to the other client's room.

Make sure to have users join a communal room, rather than other people's rooms.